# A General GRE Quantitative Problem: triangle inside circle

Tags: geometry

**Question**:

[image]

**What I know about this question**: I know nothing about the relationships among the sides of the triangle. If I were to draw a line down from $A$ to what looks like the center of $AO$, I would form a 60-30-90 triangle, but again, since I do not know the exact lengths of sides, I'm still stuck.

Comment: Hint: in an equilateral triangle (like $AOB$), all sides are the same length.

Comment: @IanColey - Wow, how did I miss that? Didn't realize it was equilateral for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that the radius is $r = OA = OB$, so $\angle A = \angle B$. But then since angles in a triangle must add up to $180^\circ$, it follows that $\triangle OAB$ is equilateral. So we can easily get the radius from the perimeter, which can be used to get the circumference.